# How to remove from array any string with 1 character?

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

So if you have an array:

```
$ourArray[0] = "a";
$ourArray[1] = "bb";
$ourArray[2] = "c";
$ourArray[3] = "ddd";
```

Is there an shorter way to remove all of the single character values from array than running array through a foreach statement and checking each one individually?

Or is this the quickest/best way to do this task?:

```
foreach( $ourArray as $key => $value){
    if(strlen($value) == 1){ unset($ourArray[$key]); }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach? Is it slow? Does is consume too much memory? Are you looking for an array function that does not iterate entire array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to achieve this,

```
$arr = [
  'test',
  '1',
  'g',
  'test-two'
];

var_dump(array_filter($arr, function ($v) {
  return strlen($v) > 1;
}));
```

If you want to ensure blank spaces are accounted for then use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on the value before [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) is used.

**Note:** The key formation will get ruined so you can reorganise them with [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/DarkorchidIntelligentTransformations) - `array_filter` without`array_values`

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/GorgeousSandyExecutables) - `array_filter` using `array_values` on the returned array of `array_filter`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a classic loop or `array_filter()` with iterated calls of `strlen()` or `mb_strlen()`, then using a simple **reg**ular **ex**pression with `preg_grep()` can be used to keep any values with 2 or more characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/emSPg))

```
var_export(
    preg_grep('/../u', $ourArray)
);
```

---

To explicitly filter out elements containing a single character, then match the full string. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XN3DQ))

```
var_export(
    preg_grep('/^.$/u', $ourArray, PREG_GREP_INVERT)
);
```